# Vehicle Routing with Different Vehicle Speed (Google OR Tools)

Tags: python, or-tools

Currently, I am working on the vehicle routing problems with different vehicle speeds.
My approach is using speed adjustment ratio for each vehicle (which mean I have default speed), to build the time constraint I used the code:
(`data['travel_service']` is time matrix + service time and `data['travel_service']` is service time only)

```
data['vehicle_speed_adjustment'] = [1.5, 1.3, 1.2, 1]
def create_vehicle_travel_service_time_callback(travel_service_matrix, service_time, speed_adjust_ratio):
    def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the travel time between the two nodes + the service time of starting node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        if travel_service_matrix[from_node][to_node] == sys.maxsize or travel_service_matrix[from_node][to_node] == service_time[from_node]:
            return travel_service_matrix[from_node][to_node]
        else:
            return int((travel_service_matrix[from_node][to_node]-service_time[from_node])/speed_adjust_ratio) + service_time[from_node]
    return time_callback

# time_callback_index = []
for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
    time_callback = create_vehicle_travel_service_time_callback(data['travel_service'], data['service_time'], data['vehicle_speed_adjustment'][vehicle_id])
    time_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)
    print(time_callback_index)
    routing.AddDimension(
        time_callback_index,
        max_waiting_time,  # allow waiting time
        max_operation_time,  # maximum time per vehicle
        False,  
        'Time')
    
time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')
```

The problem is, when I try to run the program, the program only recognize the first value of the `data['vehicle_speed_adjustment']` list which is 1.5 and applied it into every vehicle.

Can someone explain why this happens?

```
data['travel_service'] = [[0, 4, 22, 21, 48, 28, 8, 23, 16, 14, 23, 37], [59, 0, 79, 78, 104, 84, 63, 76, 68, 66, 78, 91], [32, 34, 0, 12, 38, 32, 31, 14, 41, 40, 41, 52], [27, 29, 8, 0, 35, 28, 27, 11, 36, 35, 37, 47], [58, 59, 38, 39, 0, 39, 52, 41, 62, 61, 60, 60], [36, 37, 30, 30, 37, 0, 32, 30, 41, 40, 39, 34], [18, 18, 31, 31, 52, 34, 0, 32, 20, 19, 22, 39], [33, 31, 14, 15, 41, 32, 32, 0, 42, 41, 43, 54], [44, 41, 59, 58, 80, 61, 38, 60, 0, 31, 36, 53], [69, 66, 85, 84, 106, 87, 64, 86, 58, 0, 65, 83], [33, 33, 41, 41, 60, 41, 22, 43, 18, 20, 0, 31], [45, 44, 50, 49, 58, 34, 37, 52, 33, 36, 29, 0]]

data['travel_service'] = [0, 55, 10, 6, 10, 8, 10, 10, 28, 55, 10, 8]

data['num_vehicles'] = 4
```

Comment: Something went wrong when you pasted the code and the indentation is not correct (e.g. function defs start at the same level). Can you fix it so we can better understand your code?

Comment: Is there a chance you can also provide a few rows of the data dataframe ?

Comment: already added some of the data

Comment: What is the type of data? Is it a dictionary ? 
Have you tried printing the  `data['vehicle_speed_adjustment'][vehicle_id]` just before passing it to `create_vehicle_travel_service_time_callback` to check if this value is correct ?

Comment: yes the data is dictionary. I already checked it and the value is right. But, when I tried to print after the `time_callback`, it's start to only recognize the first value of the `data['vehicle_speed_adjustment']`.

Comment: I think that you have omitted parts of the code and as a result what you posted is not reproducible. For example, `create_vehicle_travel_service_time_callback` returns the results of `time_callback`, which in turn expects from_index and to_index as arguments but you pass neither of them. Provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nearly good, you just need to create an array of callback index then pass the array to AddDimension...
note: array length MUST be equal to the vehicle number.
note2: you can reuse the same registered callback index for few vehicles
e.g. you have two bikes, and three cars in this order you could pass an array `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]` supposing `RegisterTransitCallback()` returned `1` and `2`...

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/45770b833997f827d322e929b1ed4781c4e60d44/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L416-L418

```py
time_callback_indices = []
for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
    time_callback = create_vehicle_travel_service_time_callback(data['travel_service'], data['service_time'], data['vehicle_speed_adjustment'][vehicle_id])
    time_callback_indices.append(routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback))
    #print(time_callback_index)

routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleTransits(
    time_callback_indices,
    max_waiting_time,  # allow waiting time
    max_operation_time,  # maximum time per vehicle
    False,  
    'Time')
```